# Redactor customization: imagePosition, Craft 3.7

Tags: redactor

I have Redactor customized like this

*standard.json*

```
    "imagePosition": {
  "left": "image-left",
  "right": "image-right",
  "center": "image-center"
  }
```

This works fine, and generates
`<figure class="image-left">`
for example.

However, when I add additional options:

```
"imagePosition": {
  "left 1/2": "image-left",
  "left 1/3": "image-left-onehalf",
  "right 1/2": "image-right",
  "right 1/3": "image-right-onethird", 
  "center": "image-center"
  }
```

[image: redactor]

They do not appear in the dropdown. They are in the page source, however.

Am I misunderstanding how this customization works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this helps, but I'm using the [redactor-image-class plugin](https://github.com/simplicateca/redactor-image-class) and my json looks like this:

```
    "imageClasses" : [
    { "label": "Right 30%(portrait)",   "class": "right30" },
    { "label": "Right 50%(landscape)",  "class": "right50" },
    { "label": "Full width",   "class": "fullWidth", "default": true }
  ],
```

Comment: Thanks! I submitted a request to edit the install instructions slightly. The imageclass.js file needs to go in _craft/config/redactor/plugins/_ and that makes things work.